# Equivalent logical statements confusion

Tags: logic

First time posting here. If we have the logical statement ($A$ and $B$)  $\rightarrow$ $C$ ($1$), we know that it is equivalent to ($A$ and $B$) $\rightarrow$ ($C$ and $A$) ($2$). Therefore if we wanted to prove the $\iff$ case for the first statement, we would need to prove $C$ $\rightarrow$ ($A$ and $B$). All good here. And if we wanted to prove the second statement's $\iff$ case we would have to prove ($C$ and $A$) $\rightarrow$ ($A$ and $B$). Now I would like to ask, as ($1$) and ($2$) are the same, why is showing  ($C$ and $A$) $\rightarrow$ ($A$ and $B$) not identical to showing ($C$ )  $\rightarrow$ ($A$ and $B$)?
Thank you all so much for reading.

Comment: Why do you say that showing the reciprocals is not "identical" ? Showing the direct statements is also not "identical".

Comment: What does "the second statement's $\iff$ case" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Let $B$ be $\text{true}$. The direct theorems simplify to

$$(A\implies C)\equiv(A\implies C\land A).$$

Now with $B$ $\text{false}$,

$$(\text{false}\implies C)\equiv(\text{false}\implies C\land A)$$ which are trivially correct.

If we now look at the inverses,

$$(C\implies A)\equiv(C\land A\implies C)$$

and

$$(C\implies\text{false})\equiv( C\land A\implies\text{false}),$$ we can easily find counter-examples.

The reason is that $C\land A$ is a stronger condition than $C$ alone, it takes both $A$ and $C$ to be true.